# NUnit unit test fails with correct expected result

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

When running NUnit unit testing, I receive the following output:
`Message: Expected: <Data.Models.Address>`
`But was: <Data.Models.Address>`

As shown in the below image
 [image: NUnit Output]

I am running the application under .NET 3.5 and using NUnit 2.6.3 as I believe this is the latest version I can use with .NET 3.5. Is there any reason that a unit test would fail in this way? Is there a way to fix this or am I just boned?

Comment: No one can help if you show the output without showing the test and what these classes are. It's a bit like saying that you have a calculator and it's not working because it said the answer is 5. Without knowing what the input is we can't know what the correct output should be.

Comment: Just for everyone else's reference; you need to override the Equals operator in the classes your testing against. My simple implementation was, `public override bool Equals(object obj) { return obj.GetType() == GetType(); }`.

Answer (score 1):

I normally get this type of error not because any weirdness of NUnit but because you're checking objects that aren't the same reference. If you paste your test would have a better idea of what's going on but it seems to me that you would fix it if you assert on the object that you for example return from a mock if that's your case. For example:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    //Arrange
    const string id = "the id"
    var address = new Address{Id = id};
    var repository = new Mock<IRepository>(); //Using Moq here
    repository.Setup(r => r.Get(id))
              .Returns(address);
    var sut = new AddressManager(repository.Object);

    //Act
    var returnedAddress = sut.GetAddress(id);

    //Assert
    repository.VerifyAll(); //Checks you're calling the repository with the "id"
    Assert.That(returnedAddress, Is.EqualTo(address)); // This will pass because the reference is the same
}
```

That's how I normally do the Equals unless I want to test specific property values of the address, however that type of tests would be found in classes like mappers or similar. I have never overriden the Equals btw.

Hope it does make sense.

Comment: This is really great, and thank you for taking the time. Unfortunately I was not able to modify the test cases, so adding `Is.EqualTo(object)` wouldn't have been an option. :/ This is awesome though, and I shall bookmark it. :D

Answer (score -1):

Override Equals resolved this frustration with NUnit AreEqual(obj a, obj b)

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType() == GetType();
}
```

Of course you would want to check all the data to ensure that Obj_A is actually equal to Obj_B.

Comment: that's probably because you were doing something like Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedAddress, ActualAddress); you could also just check against the relevant properties: Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedAddress.Name, ActualAddress.Name) etc (if you don't need to check too many, too ofteh - otherwise the Equals override is obviously the way to go)

Comment: As always, it's dependend on context but testing that a.Equals(b) when equality only checks on type sounds like a weird implementation of equality + test case to me. So the only relevant thing for this test is verifying whether any address gets returned? You don't care if it's the correct address for example?

Comment: Right. I know I could easily check all the properties, but I just want to make sure the types are coming back appropriately. Plus, by the time I figured this out I was ready to flip my desk, so a basic implementation was all I needed to showcase that I got the application up and running.